# Why does the Corpus Luteum produce more Progesterone than Estrogen?

Tags: physiology, reproduction, cycle

In the human ovarian cycle, follicular cells produce only Estrogen in high concentrations (to my knowledge). Yet after ovulation and formation of CL, which should be the remnant follicular cell mass, it is seen that Progesterone is secreted in higher concentration, along with some estrogen. Is this due to some structural change, or is it the effect of LH, or something else entirely? This may have an obvious answer, so I apologize in advance for my ignorance, since it is my first time using this website.

Comment: Welcome, Sriram! What did you find when you googled this? You need to show an attempt to answer this. (Hover over the down vote arrow.) Some people take offense at this. Isn't this a Q&A site? Yes, but it's an "advanced" Q&A site, so to speak. This requirement is puzzling to many, but it is not personal or meant to make you feel "less than". We do (often gladly) answer even basic questions that show research. Every site has a culture; this is ours. We're not trying to be unwelcoming. Please edit to include what you found. It's a good question, basic for an endocrinologist, but hey... ;-)

Comment: @anongoodnurse 8 months late, but still haven't found any good information. The internet is telling me the purpose of the change in hormones (to prepare the endometrium for implantation), but not the actual cause - as in some physiological change in the Graafian follicles, or external stimulus etc. However, there are articles that mention how and why an LH surge occurs and promotes ovulation, but that's not the hormone that I'm interested in.

Comment: Sriram, I would love to help you, and will, but you **must** provide a quote and a link to a *relevant* article. I googled, "Why does the Corpus Luteum produce more Progesterone than Estrogen?" and got a perfectly good scientific article that discusses all aspects of the corpus luteum high up on the first page.